# How to install opencv_contrib on Windows?

Tags: python, c++, windows, opencv, ffmpeg

I want to use the `function createFisherFaceRecognizer()` in python,but when I wrote down `model = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()` or `cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()` 
Error will occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\My projects\test\RecognizeMe.py", line 5, in 
>       model = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

I referenced the methods online and found that I should install ***opencv_contrib***.But I was stucked when I was configureing the ***opencv*** using ***CMake***.
Error:

> CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:895 (file):   file DOWNLOAD
>   HASH mismatch
>
> ```
> for file: [E:/opencv-3.1.0/sources/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ffmpeg/downloads/35fe6ccdda6d7a04e9056b0d73b98e76/opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll]
>   expected hash: [35fe6ccdda6d7a04e9056b0d73b98e76]
>     actual hash: [5171a37169c5e695c556c85dc3103d13]
>          status: [28;"Timeout was reached"]
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):   3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:15
>   (ocv_download)   cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:206 (include)
>   CMakeLists.txt:536 (include)
>
> CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:899 (message):   Failed to
>   download opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll.  Status=28;"Timeout was reached" Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.cmake:15
>   (ocv_download)   cmake/OpenCVFindLibsVideo.cmake:206 (include)
>   CMakeLists.txt:536 (include)

How to solve this problem?Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well,After trying all kinds of methods,using CMAKE and VS2013 doesn't work.
But I found a package opencv_contrib_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-none-win32.whl,just `pip install` it then it worked.
Here is a download Link:[Download opencv_contrib_python.whl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python/3.2.0.7#downloads)